# In absence of or in the absence of

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

I am wondering whether the first phrase is correct? It seems to be in use ( based on Google searches). If it is, in what cases should we use it instead of the form with 'the'? Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both are technically correct. It would be a use case specific problem. It seems titles (of texts, papers and such) that include the phrase tend to favour dropping 'the' for brevity.

Google shows 120 thousand UK hits for "in abscence of" and over twenty times as many UK hits for "in the abscence of".

Comment: You could add the relevant Google ngrams.